# El footer no se queda abajo

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Busqué y ninguna solución me sirvió.
En el home, el footer si se queda abajo y no molesta.
Pero en esta parte de mi web no, y ya no sé que más intentar.
Ya intenté `bottom = 0` y demás propiedades pero no le entiendo.

(Es un tp para la facultad, son varios ejercicios, por lo tantos hay más estilos que no se usan en esa parte del HTML)

Si pueden ver en la imagen hay un espacio en blanco debajo del footer

### -----------------------------------------

### -----------------------------------------

### -----------------------------------------

### -----------------------------------------

---

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#Header{
    background: rgb(119, 97, 206);
    height: 80px;
}


#Logo{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#Logo a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;    
}

.Ejercicios{    
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 170px;
}


h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #cccccc;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background-position: center;
    color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

form{
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 540px;
}

label{
    margin-right: 600px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.Inputs{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0.5px solid rgb(159, 138, 241);
    margin-right: 500px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#TextoResaltado{
    color: rgb(119, 97, 206);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#Boton{
    background: rgb(119, 97, 206);
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 7px 6px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.158);
}

#Boton:hover{
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    background: rgb(90, 55, 231);
}

.Integrantes{    
    margin-top: 120px;
    background: rgb(248, 252, 255);
    overflow: hidden;

}

#Titulo{
    padding: 50px;
}

#Titulo h1{
    color: rgb(110, 65, 255);
}

.Fotos{
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 620px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
}

img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 470px;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover{
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    filter: none;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(110, 65, 255); 
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#Parrafo{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px; 
    color: rgb(110, 65, 255); 
}

#Footer{
    background: black;
    height: 70px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);  
    bottom: 0;  
}

#Footer p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-top: 0.3%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h4{
    padding-top: 0.8%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    background-position: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
    
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Trabajo Práctico N°1</title>
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'css/style.css'/> 
</head>

<body>
    
    <header id='Header'>
        <nav id='Menu'>
             <ul>
                <li id='Logo'><a href='home.php'>Programación II</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    

    <div class='Ejercicios'>
                <h3>Ejercicio N°3</h2>
                <h1>Tu Horóscopo</h1>
                <form padding-bottom = '1000px'>
                <label>Resultado:</label>
                <input type='text' value='$resultado' class='Inputs' id='TextoResaltado' readonly></input>
                </form>
    </div>

    <footer id='Footer'>
        <h4>2019</h4>
        <p>UTN - Programación II - Profesor: Javier Cantó</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te comento que al menos yo ejecutando el código que has publicado si veo el footer abajo, ¿pudieras explicarnos mejor?

Comment: Ahí agregué una imagen para que veas

Answer (score 3):

La solucion para bajar el footer es cambiando la regla CSS por esta otra:

```
#Footer{
    background: black;
    height: 70px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);  
    /*  poner footer abajo */
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

La magia la hace la regla **position: fixed**

**Un elemento con posición: fixed;** se posiciona en relación con la ventana gráfica, lo que significa que siempre permanece en el mismo lugar, incluso si se desplaza la página. Las propiedades superior, derecha, inferior e izquierda se utilizan para colocar el elemento.

Cualquier informacion adicional consulta en este Link:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Asi te va a funcionar...

Answer (score 2):

Podrías agregar estas propiedades:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.Ejercicios {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[Aquí](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) hay varias soluciones a lo que buscas.

Comment: con solo el min-height en 100vh basta, el problema casi siempre se da cuando no hay suficiente contenido

Answer (score 0):

los elementos flotados están aplicando al footer
utiliza esto:

```
footer{
    clear: both;
}
```

Saludos :D

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/315229)